# How do I keep my attachments (in Outlook 2013) from moving that are in my SharePoint (2015) Calendar connected to Outlook?

Tags: calendar, sharepoint-calendar, outlook

My work used to use Outlook Calendars for business as usual, but then I persuaded them to use SharePoint Calendars and just connect them to Outlook and it is essentially the same thing, but better for tracking events and whatnot

The only problem we have is that whenever we drag an attachment to a specific spot in the event, it won't stay there. It goes down to the last line that the cursor was on, which we find annoying. This never used to happen until we started using the SharePoint Calendar on Outlook so we know it is caused by SharePoint. How do we stop the attachments from moving?

Comment: Please post the versions of sharepoint and office you are referring to.